# Problema ao inserir JTextField dentro de JPanel que está dentro de JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jpanel

Tenho uma aplicação em Swing onde a janela principal é composta por um `JtabbedPane` que contém algumas classes que estendem `JPanel` [ViewPrincipal,ViewCadastro, ViewRelatorio, etc...].

Quando adiciono JLabels e JButtons, eles aparecem e as janelas funcionam normalmente, mas quando instancio um `JTextField` ou `JTextArea` dentro de uma dessas classes que estendem `JPanel`, o JTabbedPanel buga e não aparece nada.

Se tentar um this.setLayout(null) o JTabbedPane e JPanels funcionam, mas nenhum componente interno dos JPanels aparecem. Sinto que isso de setar Layout null é muito feio.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Colocando o mínimo de coisas possíveis do código do ViewCadastro temos:

```
public class ViewCadastro extends JPanel{

        public ViewCadastro(){
            this.gettingStart();
        }

        public void gettingStart(){
            this.setBackground(Color.lightGray);    

            this.painelHeader = new JPanel();       
            this.painelHeader.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            this.painelActions = new JPanel();
            this.painelActions.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

            this.labTitulo = new JLabel("Titulo: ");
            this.painelHeader.add(labTitulo);
            //this.txTitulo = new JTextField();
            //this.painelHeader.add(txTitulo);

            this.btnAdicionarFilme = new JButton("Add");        

            this.painelActions.add(btnAdicionarFilme);
            this.add(painelHeader);
            this.add(painelActions);    

        }


        private JButton btnAdicionarFilme;
        private JPanel painelHeader;
        private JPanel painelActions;
        public JLabel labTitulo;
        public JTextField txTitulo; 
}
```

Se tirar os comentários ele já zoa tudo.

E a View Principal:

```
public class View extends JFrame{


    public View(Control controller){
        this.setCtrl(controller);
        this.gettingStart();
    }


    public void gettingStart(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(1000,500);


        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        painelPrincipal = new ViewPrincipal();
        painelCadastro = new ViewCadastro();
        painelRelatorios = new ViewRelatorios();


        //Adicionando paineis

        tabs.add("Principal",painelPrincipal);
        tabs.add("Cadastros",painelCadastro);
        tabs.add("Relatórios",painelRelatorios);

        this.add(tabs);
    }

    private Control ctrl;   
    private ViewCadastro painelCadastro;
    private ViewRelatorios painelRelatorios;
    private ViewPrincipal painelPrincipal;
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
}
```

O controle principal:

```
public class Control {

    private View viewer;

    public Control(){
        setViewer(new View(this));
    }

    public View getViewer() {
        return viewer;
    }

    public void setViewer(View viewer) {
        this.viewer = viewer;
    }
}
```

Puxado pelo main padrãozão:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Control();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO:

Na View principal (não onde instancio o JTextField, mas na classe que expande o JFrame] eu setei o JFrame '.setVisible(true);' no início na inicialização da janela. Só de mudar esses comandos para o fim da função já resolveu o problema.

Código atual:

```
public class View extends JFrame{


    public View(Control controller){
        this.setCtrl(controller);
        this.gettingStart();
    }


    public void gettingStart(){



        tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        painelPrincipal = new ViewPrincipal();
        painelCadastro = new ViewCadastro();
        painelRelatorios = new ViewRelatorios();


        //Adicionando paineis

        tabs.add("Principal",painelPrincipal);
        tabs.add("Cadastros",painelCadastro);
        tabs.add("Relatórios",painelRelatorios);

        this.add(tabs);

        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(1000,500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private Control ctrl;   
    private ViewCadastro painelCadastro;
    private ViewRelatorios painelRelatorios;
    private ViewPrincipal painelPrincipal;
    private JTabbedPane tabs;

    public Control getCtrl() {
        return ctrl;
    }

    public void setCtrl(Control ctrl) {
        this.ctrl = ctrl;
    }
}
```